# Where can I find a technical description of Chromium's "kiosk mode"?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, kiosk

I am trying to evaluate if Chromium's "kiosk mode", enabled via command-line argument, is suitable for my purposes.

Where can I find an accurate technical description of the effect of the `--kiosk` argument?

Any of these would be helpful:

- a link to a commented piece of code in Chromium's source tree
- a link to an official wiki page or official blog post
- a link to an issue in Chromium's issue tracker

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Disambiguation

There are two distinct concepts in Chrome, both of which use the name *kiosk mode*.

1. When running Chrome as a traditional web browser on a desktop OS (i.e. Windows, Mac OS X, Linux), the command-line argument `--kiosk` may be passed, causing the web browser to run in so-called *kiosk mode*.
2. A Chrome App may declare itself to be a [Kiosk App](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/kiosk_enabled), and a ChromeOS device may be configured to run that app in *kiosk mode*.

These two concepts are completely unrelated!

To avoid confusion, I shall refer to them respectively as:

1. *desktop kiosk mode*, and
2. *ChromeOS kiosk mode*.

This question asked for a technical description of *desktop kiosk mode*.

---

### ChromeOS Kiosk Mode

Remember that Google's strategy is for Chrome to be an app' delivery mechanism.

This is a much deeper strategy than simply "make a better web browser", and it informs many of the design decisions in Chrome.

For example, unlike other browsers, Chrome does not show browser controls (forward / back, address bar, etc.) when running Chrome fullscreen.  Requests to add such controls are [rejected](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8022), as they would conflict with the goal of having rich web applications providing their own navigation metaphor.

*ChromeOS kiosk mode* is an officially supported feature, and is consistent with Google's wider strategy in this area.

You can find technical information about it on the web; the feature has a label in the issue tracker; people appear to be successfully building software with it.

Critically: you can reason about it, and there's an expectation that it won't suddenly break or disappear in the next version.

---

### Desktop Kiosk Mode

Despite appearances, this is **not** an officially supported feature.

The reason that no information can be found online is that **no such information exists**.

The feature was originally accepted as a patch in late 2009 ([see #23145](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=23145)), to mimic an existing feature in Internet Explorer.

I have browsed through the source code and have discovered that it currently does (at least) these things:

- force fullscreen (and suppress the notification 'bubble')
- disable developer tools
- disable context menu
- suppress requests for extra permissions (e.g. location)

However, it also:

- doesn't suppress navigation (back / forward) via keyboard shortcut
- doesn't suppress clipboard actions via keyboard shortcut
- doesn't suppress printing
- doesn't suppress zooming
- etc.

There is basically **no definition** of how *desktop kiosk mode* should function (i.e. no formal analysis of requirements), it is simply a bunch of UI hacks that are lying around in the codebase with apparently little ownership.

The only test coverage (which executes only on Windows) is this:

```
IN_PROC_BROWSER_TEST_F(KioskModeTest, MAYBE_EnableKioskModeTest) {
  // Check if browser is in fullscreen mode.
  ASSERT_TRUE(browser()->window()->IsFullscreen());
  ASSERT_FALSE(browser()->window()->IsFullscreenBubbleVisible());
}
```

It is no surprise therefore that there are plenty of regressions (e.g. [#470265](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=470265), [#552778](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=552778)) between versions.

With no requirements, and no test coverage, things can go wrong anywhere along the boundary between the browser and the operating system, and that boundary is massive.

Input methods (on-screen keyboards etc.) are particularly interesting for kiosks, but there are regressions (e.g. [#491516](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=491516)) between versions.

Printing is a particularly bad area: there are additional command-line arguments (e.g. `--kiosk-printing`, `--disable-print-preview`) which multiplies the complexity, and the bug tracker is littered with regressions in this area.

There is no attempt to integrate with Mac OS X's kiosk API, which would prevent access to the dock etc..

Interestingly, you cannot guarantee that you are even in *desktop kiosk mode*, as the command-line argument can fail silently ([#566496](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=566496)).

The most troubling aspect is that the code simply has no owner.  Looking through the issue tracker comments, most dev's seem ignorant that *desktop kiosk mode* even exists!  It is frequently confused with *ChromeOS kiosk mode*, with bugs being mis-labelled.  It is described variously as "not well supported", and there is even a suggestion ([#470265](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=470265)) that it should simply be removed.  The only Chromium dev' who expresses vague affection for the feature is [pkasting@chromium.org](http://pkasting@chromium.org).

I haven't begun to look at the more interesting areas, e.g.:

- how does it interact with Safe Browsing?
- how does it interact with Chrome Extensions?
- what if the user visits a page with a certificate problem?
- how does it affect the software update mechanism?

---

### Conclusion

Do **not** use the `--kiosk` flag (*desktop kiosk mode*) in your system.

- you cannot reason about the security of such a system
- updates to Chrome are likely to break your system

If you want to use the Chrome ecosystem to build a kiosk system, using ChromeOS seems a better choice.

Comment: Somebody, at some point, should say that this is a brilliant answer ... Ok, I'll do it :) Best info I have come across on this topic. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Chromium's source code is, "[indexed and available on the web](https://www.chromium.org/developers/code-browsing-in-chromium)" for this very reason.

Using [Code Search](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch), you can search `kiosk` against the [entire project](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#search/&q=kiosk&sq=package:chromium&type=cs).

An excerpt of one of the [first searches](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/startup/startup_browser_creator_impl.cc&q=%5C--kiosk&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=371) I used that might interest you,

```
  // In kiosk mode, we want to always be fullscreen, so switch to that now.
  if (base::CommandLine::ForCurrentProcess()->HasSwitch(switches::kKioskMode) ||
      base::CommandLine::ForCurrentProcess()->HasSwitch(
          switches::kStartFullscreen)) {
    // It's possible for there to be no browser window, e.g. if someone
    // specified a non-sensical combination of options
    // ("--kiosk --no_startup_window"); do nothing in that case.
    Browser* browser = BrowserList::GetInstance()->GetLastActive();
    if (browser)
      chrome::ToggleFullscreenMode(browser);
  }
```

Comment: Indeed, I am pulling the whole source tree to do some searches locally.  However, if kiosk mode functionality is distributed widely across the source it will be painful to analyse, and the word 'kiosk' seems quite overloaded with some concept of a 'kiosk app' in ChromeOS.  What's bizarre is that at some point, someone must have defined the business requirements for kiosk mode - where are these?  Where are the acceptance criteria for asserting "Chromium does / not implement kiosk mode correctly"?  A comment, a ticket, a suite of tests, a wiki page, there must be some definition of the feature.